# Ошибка «The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future»

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

При использовании MySQL получаю такую ошибку:

> [8192] mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in line 14 in /config.php

Что она означает, и как её исправить?

Comment: Вам всё написали — Оригинальное API MySQL устарело и будет удалено в будущем, используйте [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Вернее будет сказать, что оно уже удалено в php 7+

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка означает, что mysql_connect() устарел, и лучше использовать внешнее PDO или использовать mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Или в таком виде:

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db   = 'test';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
?>
```